# Is there any way to force the dropdown (select) arrow control to be on the right?

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

I am using direction:rtl in a select element. It does exactly what I need which is:

- expand the options to the left when dropdown is open
- options text is right aligned

**Question: Is there any way to force the arrow control to be on the right?**

Reason why I need the select like this:

I need those because the dropdown is located on the right edge of a page and if I expand it to the right (as default), the options text won´t show up completely. The options text are very long.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's good way to manipulate the control. If you want to customize, you should make your own.

Or, you can use something already made by someone like [jQuery selectBox](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/js/jquery/selectBox/). You may can customize it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible in your situation but if you can put `direction:rtl` on the whole page, the select will probably expand to the left, thus making your question a moot point.

Comment: Using RTL brings other undesirable side effects. This attribute exists for languages that are written from the right to the left.